# recortar un string por un delimitador php

Tags: php

Necesito recortar palabras después de `", "` en `PHP`

Tengo algo parecido a esto `$string = "dato, dato, dato"`, es el mismo nombre solamente que se repite.

Comment: Probaste utilizando `split`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar [explode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) para dividir un string en varios string. Descripción:

```
array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit = PHP_INT_MAX ] )
```

- delimiter: El string delimitador.
- string: El string de entrada.

Por ejemplo:

```
$string = 'dato1, dato2, dato3';
$datos = explode(", ", $string);
var_dump($datos);
```

Salida:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "dato1" [1]=> string(5) "dato2" [2]=> string(5) "dato3" }
```